# How can I use Firebase/Google cloud functions to receive Apple's subscription status url notifications?

Tags: url, google-cloud-functions, in-app-subscription, apple-developer

I have an iOS app that uses auto-renewable subscriptions and is hence eligible to receive server-to-server-notifications from App Store Connect upon subscription changes. Given that I have no prior experience with Cloud Functions or server-to-server notifications, I am having trouble figuring out how to receive the notifications, extract and process its content and store the relevant information in my database.

I am finding very few information on that in general on the Internet. I have researched HTTPS requests, how to process them in Google Cloud Functions and so on, but I have nothing to show for it really, given that every solution I tried so far failed.

Hence, I need some guidance on the steps that I have to do to receive the Apple subscription status URL notifications and process them within Firebase to keep track of how many users are subscribed to my app.

Answer (score 0):

See my code and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742537/only-receiving-part-of-apple-subscription-notification-in-google-cloud-function/59753580#59753580).

You will also need to set the URL for the server to server communications for your app in App Store Connect to be the URL for the Google Cloud Functions, which you can  find by clicking on functions in your console.