# Only Receiving Part of Apple Subscription Notification in Google Cloud Function

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set up a Google Cloud Function (GCF) to handle Subscription Notifications from Apple.  I am familiar with GCF, but not very familiar with writing my own REST API and the Nodejs methods of handling the data Apple sends with the notification.  I am receiving the Apple notification, but only a "chunk" of it.  Here's my code (using express and body-parser frameworks).  I put my whole function here to help people since there is absolutely nothing about how to use GCF for Subscription Notifications anywhere I could find on the web (note this code is very much a work in progress and I am new to Nodejs):

```
// Set up express object
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

exports.iosNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
console.log("We are receiving a request from Apple.");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
let receipt = req.body.latest_receipt;

console.log(req.body);

const chunks = [];
req.on('data', chunk => {
    chunks.push(chunk);
    console.log('A chunk of data has arrived:', chunk);
});
req.on('end', () => {
    const data = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log('Data: ', data);
    console.log('No more data');
});

const type = req.body.notification_type;
console.log("Notification type: ", type);
const lri = req.body.latest_receipt_info;
console.log(lri, receipt);
// Verify the receipt.
validateAppleReceipt(receipt)
        .then((appleResponse) => {
            console.log("Receipt from App Store server validated.", appleResponse);
                res.sendStatus(200);
            const oTxId = appleResponse.latest_receipt_info[0].original_transaction_id;
            // Receipt is valid and we let Apple know.  Let's process the notification.
            switch (type) {
                case 'CANCEL':
                    // User canceled the subscription (like on accidental purchase).
                    console.log("User canceled a subscription.");

                    break;
                case 'DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_PREF':
                    console.log("The subscriber downgraded.  Effective on next renewal.  Handle.");

                    break;
                case 'DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS':
                    console.log("The subscriber downgraded or upgraded.  Effective on next renewal.  Handle.");

                    break;
                case 'DID_FAIL_TO_RENEW':
                    console.log("Subscription has a billing issue.  Check if in billing retry period.");

                    break;
                case 'DID_RECOVER':
                    console.log("Renewal of expired subscription that failed to renew.");

                    break;
                case 'INITIAL_BUY':
                    console.log("Initial purchase.  Ignored because we already handled with another function.");
                    break;
                case 'INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL':
                    console.log("Interactive renewal.  Not sure if we'll ever see this.");
                    break;
                case 'RENEWAL':
                    console.log("Renewal after failure.  Same as DID_RECOVER.  Handle there.");
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Hit default.");
                    break;
            };
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error validating receipt from App Store server.", error);      
        });
    });
```

This is the output I'm getting (which is only a portion of the notification Apple says it is sending).  I don't get `notification_type` or any of the other parts of the JSON file the Apple docs say I should be receiving:

```
{ latest_receipt: 'ewoJInNpZ25hdHVyZSIgPSAiQTNVM0FjaDJpbXRPMG53cEtrQW9 <<shortened for this post>>
```

I never see the console.log for any chunks.

What can I do to make sure I receive all the "chunks" and put them together into the complete JSON file that Apple is sending me so I can work with it?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire function code.  Right now, all I see is a function fragment, and it's not at all clear what `app` and `bodyParser` are here.  We should have enough information to potentially reproduce the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson . I added the code to show the frameworks express and bodyParser and how app is an express object.

Comment: Why are you declaring a new express app instance?  That seems completely unnecessary here.  The HTTP trigger is already providing you a request and response.  The app isn't doing anything that has an effect at runtime.

Comment: The short answer is I don't know how to write an API in Nodejs.  This is my attempt to use other information I gleaned from the internet to write one that takes the Apple data and puts it into a format I can use to check status, etc.  I am open to any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it.  It was so simple.  I just had to use req.body instead of req.  Here's the code for anyone who is trying to use Google Cloud Functions to handle Server to Server Notifications for subscriptions from Apple.

```
exports.iosNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
console.log("We are receiving a request from Apple.");
let receipt = req.body.latest_receipt;

const type = req.body.notification_type;
console.log("Notification type: ", type);
const lri = req.body.latest_receipt_info;
console.log(type, lri, receipt);
// Verify the receipt.
validateAppleReceipt(receipt)
```

See code above for how to handle the types Apple sends...

Comment: i still dont understand from where are we receiving the apple notification

      exports.iosNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      console.log("We are receiving a request from Apple.");

what is that exports.iosNotification ? is that the enpoint where the apple notification is coming from or is just the firebase url for this function